# What is the stance on "please find my bug"-questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I just discovered the review part of SO, how exciting! However, a little bit discombobulating.

I have tried to keep my personal approach to SO focused at questions closer to... how to describe it... well, missing or hard-to-find information. Questions regarding unclear API's, framework behaviour, language features, some syntax and that kind of stuff.

However, in my newly found experience of the triage, I see that it's not that uncommon with questions like ***Here is a bunch of code, something is not working, here is maybe some error message, and please find my bug***, questions that I personally would see as typical ***debug-and-google-until-sudden-revelation***-cases, cases that more often than not are basic trivial errors and where the problem more is a lack of debugging skill of the questioner than a request for hard-to-find information about some poorly documented artefact.

Now I admit that it must be the case that we have an evaluation on a sliding and subjective scale here regarding what exactly is an appropriate level of debugging and information searching, but is there any guidelines here?

I'm tempted to suggest that what I described would be something for a **debugmycode.SE** site, on pair with like codereview or codegolf, and feel that questions like these would be off-topic here.

But I'm insecure. Could you help me with my feelings so that I can comfortably conform?

Comment: It isn't that simple, *some* of them demonstrate a serious bug in a very commonly used tool or runtime that everybody should know about and needs to have a workaround for.  Reviewing and just looking at superficial aspects of a post is not a very good idea.

Comment: Its certainly possible to write a good question of this type, but they are *very* rare (and usually not be new users, unfortunately).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The close reason that is specific to requests for debugging help is

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**")
>   must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.
>   Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other
>   readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

So if the question meets all of those requirements, then apparently it's allowed.

And (as mentioned by others) there *are* some good debugging questions. For example, the bug could be caused by

a) a bug in an API or toolset
b) a common misconception about how an API works

In those cases, the question can be valuable to future visitors who run into the same problem, so those are good questions that should be answered.

Answer (score 13):

A 'debugmycode' site would be as popular as a 'digmylatrineditch' site.  Coding and testing can be fun, but debugging hardly ever is.  It's often ditch-digging - boring, methodical work with the debugger and logger, which is why selfish devs continually try to outource it to SO at no cost to themselves.

They don't care that it's much harder, or even impossible, to debug an app without the environment that they already have and anyone else would have to attempt to reproduce.

They don't care that several SO contributors may be working pointlessly in parallel to go over the same ground they have already travelled.

They want their app fixed, and don't care how as long as THEY don't have to do the grunt work.

I suspect that I would not visit such a site; I would run out of downvotes every day.

Answer (score 8):

> I'm tempted to suggest that what I described would be something for a debugmycode.SE site

That would be something more like a developerforhire.com site :)

**Some options**

Something like this should be taken on a question-by-question basis because certain circumstances can dictate what is more "appropriate".

However, you have all the standard close reasons to use which best fits something like this. "too broad" is usually a good one for something that is not much more than a code/exception log dump.

But it is best, imo, if you can have a canoncial answer that shows the OP how to do basic debugging on their own. For example, in [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) we have things like [what is a stacktrace and how do I read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) and [Unfortunately my app has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

**Don't be afraid to talk to the OP**

Commenting, especially to a new user, about what information would be more helpful is not a bad thing. Asking things like, "What have you done to debug?" and "Can you be more specific about when the problem happens" can help get better information, help the OP to learn how to ask better questions, and can also help the OP to understand how to debug for themselves a little better.